# How to reinstall crashed ambari

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, hortonworks-sandbox

I installed Ambari and Hortonworks on Centos 7.
I had many problems with the Kerberos configuration, so I tried to reinstall Ambari. 
I followed this [link](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/1110/how-to-completely-remove-uninstall-ambari-and-hdp.html), but I always get errors in the Install and test step.
So what is the best way to reinstall ambari server?

Answer (score 1):

Errors during "Install&Test" step are usually caused by conflicts with already installed HDP packages. 
Did you try to follow this link? http://web.archive.org/web/20170816163504/http://www.yourtechchick.com/hadoop/how-to-completely-remove-and-uninstall-hdp-components-hadoop-uninstall-on-linux-system/

Comment: This link is not working can you share the new link or steps

Comment: thanks for pinging me, replaced the link with a web archive version